# Facebook Cocoapods integration

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

I am integrating 3rd party libraries into my project using cocoapods. Everything was working smoothly but when i try to integrate facebook ios sdk I encounter a very strange issue, my pods project has the following warning:

[image: Validate Project settings]

If i click on it i get the following dialog:

[image: Remove Duplicates Dialog]

I checked the Headers in the build phases part of the target "Pods-Facebook-iOS-SDK". Every header file is repeating:

[image: Repeating headers]

When i try to build my project it fails because it is not able to find "FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h".

My last option is to just integrate facebook sdk manually and not use cocoapods for it but I dont want to take that route and for the life of me I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. For refrence following is my pod file:

> platform :ios, '7.0'
>
> pod 'DTCoreText'
>
> pod 'UIView+AnimationExtensions'
>
> pod 'EZAudio'
>
> pod 'MZTimerLabel'
>
> pod 'AWSAutoScaling'
>
> pod 'AWSCloudWatch'
>
> pod 'AWSCore'
>
> pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
>
> pod 'AWSEC2'
>
> pod 'AWSElasticLoadBalancing'
>
> pod 'AWSKinesis'
>
> pod 'AWSS3'
>
> pod 'AWSSES'
>
> pod 'AWSSNS'
>
> pod 'AWSSQS'
>
> pod 'AWSSimpleDB'
>
> pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'

Following is the information regarding my developement environment:

XCode: 6.1

Architectures: armv7, arm64

Base SDK: iOS 8.1

Comment: The FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h file no longer exists in v4, you should use FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h, FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h and FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem. My project previously had not used Cocoapods and I was now attempting to add the Facebook SDK via Cocapods.

Based on @MingLi's comment, I replaced all instances of `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` with `#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>` and things started working again.

When I compiled in Xcode, it showed me files that need `#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>` and `#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>`

You will also likely have to go through and adjust things that changed between Facebook SDK 3.x and 4.x. For instance, I had to replace `[FBSettings setDefaultAppId:123456789]` with `[FBSDKSettings appId:123456789]` and replace `[FBAppEvent activateApp]` with `[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp]`.

Xcode is sometimes helpful about finding the needed change, if you compile and then click the red dot (in your code) next to each compile error.

It can take a good bit of work to sort through all of the changes, you may have to recompile many times.

If you are having problems figuring out how to replace specific functions/classes when upgrading from SDK 3.x to 4.x, you can refer to Facebook's Change Log:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x

You can also find additional information here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started